# Entropy as an exact differential

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, differentiation

I have been trying to prove that $dS$ is an exact differential given this definition:

> If you have a function of two variables $z = f(x, y)$ for which $dz$ can be expressed as:
> $$dz = \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} dx\right) + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} dy\right)$$
> i.e., it has the form $dz = M dx + N dy$, then if it's an exact differential, it holds that:
> $$\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)_x = \left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)_y$$

This is what I have started to do:

$dS = \frac{\delta Q}{T} = \frac{1}{T} \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} dT +  \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + p \right] dV \right) \Rightarrow   \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \left( \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right) = \frac{\partial }{\partial T} \left( \frac{1}{T} \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + p \right] \right) $

at this point I don't really know how to proceed, can you give me some hints on what to do both on the LHS and RHS of the equation? Thank you

EDIT: I found in my notes this result
$$\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_T = T \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} - p$$
However I don't know how to get to this result and it doesn't really seem to me like it's the end result

Comment: I don't see the goal of your approach. Entropy is usually assumed to be a state function by the 2d principle, which makes its differential automatically exact. If you're not interested in the mathematical relationship between exactness and state function, you need to specify your (necessary) assumption to deduce that the entropy differential is exact (got to start somewhere).

Comment: I agree with @LPZ, once you write $dU=TdS-pdV$, with $U=U(S,V)$, there is nothing to prove anymore regarding the *existence* of $S$; this is Gibbs's approach. You may wish to prove that when you take an "inexact" two-variable differential form, such as $dU+pdV$ it always has an integrating factor, but that is a mathematical result true for *any* two-variable form without physical significance unless you also show that the integrating factor is universal and the entropy $S$ is additive. The "existence" becomes interesting for the three-variable case, such as, $du+pdV-\mu dN$, for example.

Comment: Thank you both, I see what you mean @LPZ. Maybe I was misunderstood my teachers explanation. I remember him talking about exact differential giving the definition and then I got the result $\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_T = T \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} - p$ written down so I was trying to get to that, he then used it to prove that the internal energy is only dependent on temperature...

Answer (score 4):

You *cannot* prove mathematically that $dS$ is an exact differential starting from
$$
   dS = \frac{dQ}{T}
$$
This requires the *thermodynamic* (not mathematical) proof that the quantity $dQ/T$ is a *state* function (i.e. an exact differential) when evaluated along a *reversible* path.

To prove this we use the Kelvin-Plank  statement of the second law as explained in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/780547/change-in-entropy-for-a-reversible-process/780719#780719) of mine. The Kelvin-Plank statement is a *postulate,* therefore the proof is ultimately based on a physical postulate, not on the mathematical properties of exact differentials.

Once we have proven that $dS$ *is* an exact differential we can write
$$
   dU = dQ_\text{rev} - P dV = T dS - P dV
$$
Now we can apply the conditions of the exact differential , for example,
$$
   \left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{S}
   =
   -\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial S}\right)_{V}
$$
to obtain various useful relationships.

Comment: $   dS = dQ_\text{rev} - P dV = T dS - P dV$ this is definitely nonsense. Maybe you meant $dU = \dots$

Comment: …Yes, I corrected it. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

$$dU=TdS-pdV$$
$$dS=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_TdV$$So $$dU=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_VdT+\left[T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T-p\right]dV$$

Comment: Ahh, but doesn't the derivation depend critically on the fact that $S$ is a function of state, which is just another way to say that it is exact

Comment: @By Symmetry Of course entropy is a function of state.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the final result of applying the Euler test to the exact differential of entropy, though it isn’t quite what you wanted. This is an example of what is called an “exact equation of state” and you can make some identifications of what the derivatives in your equation mean.

To get a straight up formula for entropy, you can apply [Euler’s homogeneous function theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function). Extensive variables (like entropy, energy, volume, etc.) are 1st order homogeneous functions of their extensive variables. From the [fundamental thermodynamic relation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) for the internal energy $E$,

\begin{gather*}
dE= TdS -PdV +\sum_j \mu_j dn_j \\
\implies dS = \frac{1}{T} dE + \frac{P}{T}dV -\sum_j \frac{\mu_j }{T} dn_j
\end{gather*}

Thus, entropy is a function of $E$, $V$, and $\{n_j\}$, all of which are extensive. Euler’s theorem lets us write,
\begin{gather*}
S=E \frac{\partial S}{\partial E} + V\frac{\partial S}{\partial V} + \sum_j n_j \frac{\partial S}{\partial n_j} \\ 
= \frac{E}{T} + \frac{PV}{T} - \sum_j \frac{n_j \mu_j}{T}
\end{gather*}
The specific manifestation of this equation will just depend on what the nature of your system actually is. But since this is a state function composed of other state functions, you must have an exact differential. Another perhaps much easier way to show entropy is an exact differential is to start from the Boltzmann or Gibbs definitions that are made up of the microstate multiplicities and probabilities, respectively. At that point it is manifestly clear that $S$ must be a state function.

Comment: Some kind of energy is a 2nd order homogeneous function of its extensive variable, for example, such is the case for *electrostatic* energy whose extensive variable is the electric charge.