# Proving entropy is an exact differential

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, differentiation, differential-equations

I have been trying to understand something that my professor explained and I have tried everything (books, my classmates' notes, internet) but I can't understand, can you please help retrieve the missing passage?

We were proving
that $dS$ is an exact differential given this definition:

> If you have a function of two variables $z = f(x, y)$ for which $dz$ can be expressed as:
> $$dz = \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} dx\right) + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} dy\right)$$
> i.e., it has the form $dz = M dx + N dy$, then if it's an exact differential, it holds that:
> $$\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}\right)_x = \left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)_y$$

So for entropy we can do:
$dS = \frac{\delta Q}{T} = \frac{1}{T} \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} dT +  \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + p \right] dV \right) \Rightarrow   \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \left( \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right) = \frac{\partial }{\partial T} \left( \frac{1}{T} \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + p \right] \right) $

and then by solving derivatives we get to this result:
$$\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_T = T \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} - p$$

Please I don't understand how to get here, I am asking for at least some hints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entropy as an exact differential](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/781016/)

Comment: @dgamma Not really

Comment: Let me edit your question, without counter-editing, since there is an error! And then I'll add my answer

Comment: @basics oops sorry!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial V} \left( \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right) = \frac{\partial }{\partial T} \left( \frac{1}{T} \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + P \right] \right) 
\end{equation}
where the internal energy and the pressure are meant to be functions of temperature and volume,
\begin{equation}
  U(T,V) \qquad , \qquad P(T,V) \ .
\end{equation}
Now, you only need to perform derivation of these functions
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{T} \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial T \partial V}  = - \frac{1}{T^2} \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + P \right] + \frac{1}{T} \left[ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial T \partial V} + \dfrac{\partial P}{\partial T} \right]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 \rightarrow 0 = -\dfrac{1}{T^2} \left[ \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} + P \right ] + \dfrac{\partial P }{\partial T} \ ,
\end{equation}
from which you can easily get the last equation of your question (multiplying by $T^2$).